# typescript getter / setter overload

Tags: typescript, overloading, getter-setter

Is there a way to overload a typescript getter / setter?

I know that typescript provides [function overloading](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-overloads) so i came up with something like this:

```
public get stringOrNumber(): string { return this._stringOrNumber; }

public set stringOrNumber(value: number);
public set stringOrNumber(value: string) { 
    if(typeof stringOrNumber == 'number') {
        this._stringOrNumber = value.toString();
    } else {
        this._stringOrNumber = value;
    } 
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class A {

    protected _stringOrNumber: string|number;

    public get stringOrNumber(): string|number { 
        return this._stringOrNumber; 
    }

    public set stringOrNumber(value: string|number) { 
        if(typeof this.stringOrNumber === 'number') {
            this._stringOrNumber = value.toString();
        } else {
            this._stringOrNumber = value;
        } 
    }
}
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%09%0A%09protected%20_stringOrNumber%3A%20string%7Cnumber%3B%0A%09%0A%09public%20get%20stringOrNumber()%3A%20string%7Cnumber%20%7B%20%0A%09%09return%20this._stringOrNumber%3B%20%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09public%20set%20stringOrNumber(value%3A%20string%7Cnumber)%20%7B%20%0A%09%09if(typeof%20this.stringOrNumber%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this._stringOrNumber%20%3D%20value.toString()%3B%0A%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this._stringOrNumber%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%09%09%7D%20%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)]

Comment: Hi Martin, this is definitely an improvement. But i'd prefer that the protected property and the getter just represent a string. Only the setter should have a number overload. But then i get an error because the getter and setter must have the same type :/

Comment: There is a closed issue for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2521 (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4087) Unfortunately, the current behavior is by design.

Comment: Thx so your solution is the way to go for now. Even if i dont like the fact that a property has multiple types.